# Why will this not compile with mingw in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, g++, mingw

I've striped this down to the bare bones code. Essentially, I need to pass a 2d array into a function, but the size of the array is read from a text file at execution. Everything I've read on this subject says this is the way to do it, but the compiler says otherwise. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <size_t r, size_t c>
void func(int (&a)[r][c])
{
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int rows = 5;
    int cols = 6;
    int Array[rows][cols];

    func(Array);

    return 0;
}
```

I would rather avoid vectors, since I am extremely unfamiliar with them. This is the compiler's output:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c C:\Users\ME\Desktop\test\test\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
C:\Users\ME\Desktop\test\test\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\ME\Desktop\test\test\main.cpp:20:15: error: no matching function for call to 'func(int [(((unsigned int)(((int)rows) + -0x000000001)) + 1)][(((unsigned int)(((int)cols) + -0x000000001)) + 1)])'
C:\Users\ME\Desktop\test\test\main.cpp:20:15: note: candidate is:
C:\Users\ME\Desktop\test\test\main.cpp:6:25: note: template<unsigned int r, unsigned int c> void func(int (&)[r][c])
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code

```
int rows = 5;
int cols = 6;
int Array[rows][cols];
```

the `Array` is not an ordinary C++ multi-dimensional array, but a C99 *variable length array*, or VLA.

It's not standard C++.

Instead do

```
int const rows = 5;
int const cols = 6;
int Array[rows][cols];
```

This works because the initializer expressions are known at compile time.

---

To avoid such problems, add the option **`-pedantic-errors`** to your g++ invocation.

Comment: I just used "rows" and "cols" as a stand in.The number of rows and columns will be read in from a text file at run time. Will this still work given that?

Comment: @bobsicle0 nope. numbers read from a text file are not known at compile time. use `std::vector` for your storage.